# How much gas did the attacker spend on TheDAO?

Tags: the-dao

Is there a way or somewhere I can see the gas used during the attack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://etherchain.org/account/0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413) you can see latest transactions to the child dao. [This](https://etherchain.org/tx/0xf415e83ac3283f856a20011493685a88307bf7eec210b06c00b48fcb43217561) was one of many transaction the attacker used. He sent 258.05656476038172 in each transaction. Each transaction had cost of 2,848,937 GAS with gas price at 2.6e-8 Ether. The attacker has 2436828.141032285 Ethers at his account as of now. All of the transactions were identical as far as I know, So the number of transactions is:

```
In [1]: 2436828.141032285 / 258.05656476038172
Out[1]: 9443.000000000002
```

(There is some computer rounding error, won't explain it here but its due to float point handling). With each transaction consuming 2,848,937 gas:

```
In [2]: 9443 * 2848937
Out[2]: 26902512091
```

So that is your number.